# I am using OLEDB to read excel file into datatable. some values are missing(Empty). Why OLEDB is skipping string values?

Tags: asp.net, excel, import, webforms

it has mixed values like string and integers. Most of the cell values are integers.

This is the format of the excel file which am using to upload in asp.net webforms.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQt7S.png)

Below is the dataset with missing value.Not reading that particular cell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjZxh.png)

Below is the code:

string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;

```
            switch (fileExtension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    excelConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                             .ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                    excelConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                             .ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }

            excelConnectionString = String.Format(excelConnectionString, filePath, isHDR);

            //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dt == null)
                return;

            String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int t = 0;
            //excel data saves in temp file here.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                t++;
            }

            string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);//get the first worksheet(index = 0)
            using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection))
            {
                //ds.ToString();
                dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

            }
            excelConnection.Close();
            dtUploadedChassisList = ds.Tables[0];
```

Can anyone help me if iam missing anything??

Comment: I referred to that link and even then could not resolve problem. Using IMEX=1 worked for upto 8 rows only. So added (char)34 in connection string. Its giving me error like "ISAM is not installed". Below is my connection string:  <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='+(char)34+Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1;+(char)34'" />
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='+(char)34+Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1;+(char)34'" />
@timwilliams

Comment: That would give you two literal "(char)34" strings in your connection string.